# Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowser found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, objectbox

I am working with ObjectBox DB in Kotlin, and want to use DataBrowser for ObjectBox that is shown in the [documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser). The project was running well before I made changes in the build.gradle and manifest. Now, it gives an error like this:

**> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.**

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowser found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.AndroidScheduler found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.AndroidScheduler$Runner found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.BuildConfig found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.ObjectBoxDataSource found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.ObjectBoxDataSource$1 found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.ObjectBoxDataSource$Factory found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.ObjectBoxLiveData found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)
> Duplicate class io.objectbox.android.ObjectBoxLiveData$1 found in modules objectbox-android-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1) and objectbox-android-objectbrowser-2.9.1-runtime (io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:2.9.1)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libobjectbox-jni.so'.
> If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
> https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
17 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 10 up-to-date

**BEFORE (gradle)**

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'io.objectbox'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.projectnamehere"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:2.9.1"

}
```

**AFTER (gradle)**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' // Only for Kotlin projects.
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.projectnamehere"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:2.9.1"
    debugImplementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:$objectboxVersion"
    releaseImplementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"

}
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

**BEFORE (manifest)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectnamehere">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ThemeHere">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**AFTER (manifest)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectnamehere">
    <!-- Required to provide the web interface -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Required to run keep-alive service when targeting API 28 or higher -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ThereHere">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the build.gradle file, there are two same classes that are implemented with same libraries but different keywords
releaseImplementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"
implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:2.9.1"